# Can't get LCD1602 display to work with ATmega2560

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr, atmega, lcd

I have been trying to connect an LCD1602 display to my ATmega2560 but I just can't make it work. The following code should display "Hi" on the LCD but instead it just turns it on and that's all.

Main function:

```
.INCLUDE "m2560def.inc"

.EQU    LCD_DPRT = PORTA;
.EQU    LCD_DDDR = DDRA;
.EQU    LCD_DPIN = PINA;
.EQU    LCD_CPRT = PORTB;
.EQU    LCD_CDDR = DDRB;
.EQU    LCD_CPIN = PINB;
.EQU    LCD_RS = 0;
.EQU    LCD_RW = 1;
.EQU    LCD_EN = 2;  

    LDI R21, HIGH(RAMEND)
    OUT SPH,R21
    LDI R21, LOW(RAMEND)
    OUT SPL,R21; set up stack

    LDI R21, 0xFF;
    OUT LCD_DDDR, R21; make LCD data port output
    OUT LCD_CDDR, R21; make LCD command port output;

    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_EN; LCD_EN = 0;

    CALL DELAY_2ms; wait for power on

    LDI R16, 0x38; start initializing the matrix
    CALL CMNDWRT; write to the command registers
    CALL DELAY_2ms; wait 2ms

    LDI R16, 0x0E;
    CALL CMNDWRT; 

    LDI R16, 0x01;
    CALL CMNDWRT;

    CALL DELAY_2ms;

    LDI R16, 0x06; shift cursor right
    CALL CMNDWRT;

    LDI R16, 'H';
    CALL DATAWRT;

    LDI R16, 'i';
    CALL DATAWRT;

HERE:
    JMP HERE; stay here

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the function used for writing commands

```
CMNDWRT:
    OUT LCD_DPRT, R16; send R16 to Data Port
    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_RS; make RS pin 0, to enable command sending
    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_RW; make pin RW 0,  to enable writing
    SBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_EN; make pin E 1, start of high to low signal
    CALL SDELAY; make a wide pulse
    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_EN; clear E bit
    CALL DELAY_100us; wait for the LCD to run the command;
    RET

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the function used for writing data

```
DATAWRT:
    OUT LCD_DPRT, R16; send R16 to data port
    SBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_RS; make RS pin 1, to enable data sending
    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_RW; make pin RW 0,  to enable writing
    SBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_EN; make pin E 1, start of high to low signal
    CALL SDELAY; make a wide pulse
    CBI LCD_CPRT, LCD_EN; EN = 0, for H-t-L Pulse
    CALL DELAY_100us
    RET

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the delay functions I am using

```
SDELAY:
    NOP
    NOP
    RET

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DELAY_100us:
    PUSH R17;
    LDI R17, 228; 
AGAIN:
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    DEC R17
    BRNE AGAIN
    RET

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DELAY_2ms:
    PUSH R17
    LDI R17,20; load the counter
LDR0:
    CALL DELAY_100us
    DEC R17
    BRNE LDR0
    POP R17
    RET
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timing after power-on might be too fast. Following the [HD44780 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf), at least 15 ms have to elapse before issuing the first command to the display controller.